# CSS / hide buttons on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, hide

I'm displaying social share buttons using the fowlling CSS:

```
#social_side_links {
    position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 99;
}
#social_side_links li a {display: block;}
#social_side_links li a img {
    display: block;
    max-width:25px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition:  background .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:  background .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:  background .2s ease-in-out;
  transition:  background .2s ease-in-out;
}
#social_side_links li a:hover img {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);}
```

However, I want to hide this in mobile (not tablets). What's the way to make this work?

Comment: search for **media query** and you will get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media query to hide elements on responsive.

in your case you can use :

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
#social_side_links {
    display:none;
}
```

This will hide your element on mobile (change the max width for your needs).

Answer (score 0):

[Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) are the solution. Allows you to specify styles for specific resolutions, screen formats, etc.

Fox example:

```
#social_side_links
    display: none

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #social_side_links {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

If you have to support mobile devices and they also are a priority, I suggest following a Mobile First approach, like the example.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to target mobile devices is by using `@media` queries:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #social_side_links {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can also use `@media` queries to apply CSS based on other more specific information, for example:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    ...
}
```

Official current docs for `@media` queries:

- [CSS Conditional Rules Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/).

Useful links:

- [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) (MDN)
- [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) (MDN)

---

If the above are not enough and you need even more accurate device targeting, you might want to have a look at one of the following libraries:

- [The MobileESP Project](http://blog.mobileesp.com/)
- [isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile)